# DSocuSign Reminders & NOtifications

Tags: notifications, docusignapi, reminders

I have enabled reminders and expiration in DocuSign. But when a document is sent to a user, it does not seem to work.

I'm using SOAP APIs on C#.

```
DocuSignAPI.Notification ntf = new DocuSignAPI.Notification();
DocuSignAPI.Reminders rem = new DocuSignAPI.Reminders();
rem.ReminderEnabled = true;
rem.ReminderEnabled = true;
rem.ReminderDelay = 5;
rem.ReminderFrequency = 3;
DocuSignAPI.Expirations exp = new DocuSignAPI.Expirations();
exp.ExpireEnabled = true;
exp.ExpireAfter = 90;
exp.ExpireWarn = 3;
```

Comment: Have you considered using REST API and the new client libraries that were produced for REST?

Comment: Yeah but lack of time and constantly approaching deadlines has not allowed me to implement that further.

Answer (score 0):

I set the values to 2016 and noticed that expiration was working but reminders are not. After sending the documents, I could not see the reminders set on the DS web site, if I tried to correct the document.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you make the expiration to work? I also have a c# code and using SOAP.  My code is like below:
                        DocuSignAPI.Expirations exp = new DocuSignAPI.Expirations();

 exp.ExpireEnabled = true;
exp.ExpireAfter = "128";
exp.ExpireWarn = "0";

Does not give any error, but does not set the expiration to end of 2016 either. Thanks in advance.